# How to write a function with an Observable?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I want to create a function that returns an `Observable`.The description of the function is as follows:

1. The function should be `delayedAlert(message:string, time:number)` that returns an `Observable`.
2. The function should contain `setTimeout` function inside `delayedAlert` which prints `message` after the set '`time`' value.

Ex:

```
delayedAlert(message, time){
return new Observable//how to implement setTimeout function here?
```

Comment: You can do this by reading the documentation. Take a look at `Observable.create`. Do you want the function to print the message, or do you want the observable to emit a value, and a subscriber would then print the message?

Comment: I have read the document, but could not understand how to make this successful.If you can tell me in both the ways that will add to my learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Observable.create`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-create) to create the observable, and in the first callback, write the logic to populate the observable, which in your case is the `setTimeout`.

```
function delayedAlert(msg, time) {
  return Observable.create(
    observer => setTimeout(() => observer.onNext(msg), time));
}
```

Then to use it:

```
delayedAlert("Hi, Sally", 1000).subscribe(msg => alert(msg));
```

However, if you are using observables, you don't need to use `setTimeout`; use [`delay`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay) instead, applied to [`of`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of), which creates an observable from individual value(s):

```
function delayedAlert(msg, time) {
  return Observable.of(msg).delay(time);
}
```

Since it's so easy to write it this way, you probably don't need the `delayedAlert` function at all:

```
const observable = Observable.of("Hi, Sally").delay(1000);

observable.subscribe(msg => alert(msg));
```

Comment: Do I have to import Rxjs from 'rxjs/Rx' as it shows observer.onNext is not a function.

Comment: Please try `next`. Of course you will need `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` to get access to `Observable` itself and the static and instance methods like `of`, `create`, and `delay`.

Comment: yes, it works, I have understood now the implementation of Observables. Thank you so much, People rather answering downvoted the question, they have time to downvote but no time to answer the mistakes.anyways thank you.

Comment: @Aditya Well, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial or hand-holding service. The expectation is that users are capable, on their own, of finding and digesting all the great information available on the net on virtually any topic. There are dozens of great tutorials, blog posts, and intros. Working through them is a much more efficient means of learning than asking rudimentary questions one-by-one on Stack Overflow, even leaving aside the problem that in many cases those questions will be down-voted or close-voted. Use SO when you get stuck on specific problem you can't solve.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and I understand this, but for a new person who has just started everything, finds and reads everything and every other blog takes 1 or 2 days to understand but could not able to understand the API due to lack of experience, after all these tries finally asks on SO.only that's the point.But I will soon adapt that qualtiy as well.You are correct.